# Trying to install PyQtWebEngine on a Mac OS with PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to this and not sure what to do. When running a file in PyCharm I get this message:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aqt/qt.py", line 16, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *  # type: ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

So I went to the folder:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
```

I typed this:

```
python get-pip.py
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.1
    Uninstalling pip-20.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.1
  WARNING: The scripts pip, pip2 and pip2.7 are installed in '/Users/al/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  NOTE: The current PATH contains path(s) starting with `~`, which may not be expanded by all applications.
```

and tried to enter this:

```
% pip install PyQtWebEngine
zsh: command not found: pip
```

Can anyone give me advice on what I am doing wrong and also why even though I am in the 3.8 folder does it use Python 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question but if I'll answer you what I think you ment. Please tell me if I understood it wrong.
So you go to command prompt and write : pip install PyQtWebEngine
I don't think it's important but do it anyways.
Then if you have PyCharm (what you do) go to File then settings. In settings go to
Project:_______(<- the name of your project). Press on that arrow left of it. Then go to Project Interpreter and click on it. There you will see all your installed packages of your program. So, you don't have PyQtWebEngine. Go to that + button on the right side.
Then you'll have to search for whatever package you need (now: PyQtWebEngine) and press on it. Then very down on that window you'll see the button "install package" and press on it. After a moment(time depends on your computer) it'll be installed. You can install all packages you wan't there. I don't know, maybe it's just me but just in case it's for all, here's what I wan't to still tell you:
You may have to install the packages (that you have to install) always again if you start a new project. 
Hope I solved your problem :)